# Can I access MS Search/SharePoint Search results programmatically in ASP.NET?

Tags: sharepoint, search, pdf

We would like to be able to search uploaded pdf's for keywords from out public website.

I have sucessfully configured a vm for a proof-of-concept that is crawling and indexing our (scanned and OCR'd) pdf's!  This was a pain, but it's working in a full 64-bit implementation, both with uploaded files (to SQL Server) and from a file share as my content sources.

What we would like to do is tap into the search functionality programmatically, submitting a keyword via an exposed class and recieve back either an xmlstream, generic list, or similar.  Is this possible or at least is it possible to use a "search web part" in our ASP.NET site?  We don't want to develop a full SharePoint site, but rather, just use the search results.  Sorry I'm really a database guy, new to SharePoint and fairly inexperienced in web development.

Virtual Server config:
Windows 2003 Server R2 (64-bit), 
MS Search Server 2008 Express (64-bit), 
SQL Server 2008 (64-bit), 
64-bit Adobe IFilter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the SharePoint Search Web Service

[Windows SharePoint Services Query Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms470518.aspx)

Comment: That is just what I was looking for.

Thanks Rob!

Answer (score 0):

Download the .NET helpers here:
[.NET helper classes](http://mosssrchws.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Detailed [explanation of code here][2]:
  [2]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb852171%28office.12%29.aspx